# Writing nested dictionary to Excel using openpyxl in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, openpyxl

I want to write a nested dictionary to a sheet using openpyxl in which the keys should be used as header and values which are also a inner dictionary which has list values in it as well to be the records for header in which parent keys they are present.

My code hasn't been able to achieve the complete the scenario but I was able divide data into required stages which I want but the issues are blank cells and List values which I want to be divided like:

```
LKP_GetData -> ('FIL_UpdateChangedRecord', 'EXP_DetectChanges') in stage3 which has list values should be broken to LKP_GetData -> ('FIL_UpdateChangedRecord') and LKP_GetData -> ('EXP_DetectChanges') in stage 3 and placed in individual cells. Same goes with other such data in other stages
```

My code:

```
import openpyxl

# Your nested dictionary
nested_dict = {
    0: {'DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP': ['SQ_DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP'], 'SAT_CONTACT': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER'], 'SAT_CUSTOMER_DERIVED': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER'], 'SAT_CUSTOMER': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER'], 'SAT_CUSTOMER_PREDICTED': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER'], 'HUB_CUSTOMER': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER']},
    1: {'SQ_DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP': ['UPDTRANS'], 'SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER': ['LKP_SH_MOBILE_PH_NO', 'EXP_PREPARE_DATA', 'lkp_LNK_CUSTOMER_CUST_GROUP', 'LKP_CIS_CUSTOMER', 'lkp_REF_EARLY_ADOPTERS', 'LKP_GPRS_USAGE_AVG', 'LKP_EMP_FLAG', 'lkp_SH_MOBILE_PH_Active', 'exp_MOBILE_PH_NO']},
    2: {'UPDTRANS': ['DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_Update'], 'LKP_SH_MOBILE_PH_NO': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'EXP_PREPARE_DATA': ['FIL_InsertNewRecord', 'FIL_UpdateChangedRecord', 'EXP_DetectChanges', 'LKP_GetData'], 'lkp_LNK_CUSTOMER_CUST_GROUP': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'LKP_CIS_CUSTOMER': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'lkp_REF_EARLY_ADOPTERS': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'LKP_GPRS_USAGE_AVG': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'LKP_EMP_FLAG': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'lkp_SH_MOBILE_PH_Active': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'exp_MOBILE_PH_NO': ['lkp_SH_MOBILE_PH_Active']},
    3: {'FIL_InsertNewRecord': ['UPD_ForceInserts'], 'FIL_UpdateChangedRecord': ['UPD_ChangedUpdate'], 'EXP_DetectChanges': ['FIL_InsertNewRecord', 'FIL_UpdateChangedRecord'], 'LKP_GetData': ['FIL_UpdateChangedRecord', 'EXP_DetectChanges']},
    4: {'UPD_ForceInserts': ['DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_Insert'], 'UPD_ChangedUpdate': ['DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP_Insert']}
}

# Create a new Excel workbook
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Desktop\\multiple_sheets_details_new.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.create_sheet(title = "MAPPING",index=0)


# Write headers
headers = [f'Stage{i}' for i in nested_dict.keys()]
sheet.append(headers)

# Write data to Excel
for key in set(key for inner_dict in nested_dict.values() for key in inner_dict):
    row_data = []
    for inner_dict in nested_dict.values():
        if key in inner_dict and isinstance(inner_dict[key], list):
            row_data.append(f'{key} -> {tuple(inner_dict[key])}')
        else:
            row_data.append(inner_dict.get(key, [""])[0])
    sheet.append(row_data)

# Save the workbook
workbook.save("C:\\Desktop\\multiple_sheets_details_new.xlsx")
```

The issue is I am getting an output where there are blank cells in each column record(stage 0, stage 1, etc.) and I want them to be in sequence in each column without any blank cells. Also the List values should be broken in to key value records in the same column. Like

LKP_GetData -> ('FIL_UpdateChangedRecord', 'EXP_DetectChanges') in stage3 which has list values should be broken to LKP_GetData -> ('FIL_UpdateChangedRecord') and LKP_GetData -> ('EXP_DetectChanges') in stage 3 and placed in individual cells

My Output:

[image]

I am expecting the output to look like:

[image]

Comment: If you use Openpyxl 'append' then each write will be on a separate row, the next unused row on the sheet. That is why every populated cell is on its own row.

Comment: @moken Is there any workaround I dont't want blank spaces in the columns

Comment: Sure. You can write cells individually by row/column or create [lists] that contain all the data for the row and then append. At the moment I'm still trying to comprehend exactly what your end result should look like to see what would suit. You wouldn't happen to have a screen shot of how you want the resultant sheet to look?

Comment: @moken I am adding in 5mins

Comment: @moken I have added the expected result I want.

Comment: @moken Its a like a part of a pipeline which will generate the nested dictionary and the output has to be written to excel in the format I mentioned in the excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the expected result screen shot, I was close. 
Either way the easiest is probably just reading the dict and adding the values to the cells as they are read.

Here is a quick option which I think is correct though may not be sorted the same way as your example;

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import Font

# Your nested dictionary
nested_dict = {
    0: {'DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP': ['SQ_DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP'], 'SAT_CONTACT': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER'],
        'SAT_CUSTOMER_DERIVED': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER'], 'SAT_CUSTOMER': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER'],
        'SAT_CUSTOMER_PREDICTED': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER'], 'HUB_CUSTOMER': ['SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER']},
    1: {'SQ_DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP': ['UPDTRANS'],
        'SQ_HUB_CUSTOMER': ['LKP_SH_MOBILE_PH_NO', 'EXP_PREPARE_DATA', 'lkp_LNK_CUSTOMER_CUST_GROUP',
                            'LKP_CIS_CUSTOMER', 'lkp_REF_EARLY_ADOPTERS', 'LKP_GPRS_USAGE_AVG', 'LKP_EMP_FLAG',
                            'lkp_SH_MOBILE_PH_Active', 'exp_MOBILE_PH_NO']},
    2: {'UPDTRANS': ['DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_Update'], 'LKP_SH_MOBILE_PH_NO': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'],
        'EXP_PREPARE_DATA': ['FIL_InsertNewRecord', 'FIL_UpdateChangedRecord', 'EXP_DetectChanges', 'LKP_GetData'],
        'lkp_LNK_CUSTOMER_CUST_GROUP': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'LKP_CIS_CUSTOMER': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'],
        'lkp_REF_EARLY_ADOPTERS': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'LKP_GPRS_USAGE_AVG': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'],
        'LKP_EMP_FLAG': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'], 'lkp_SH_MOBILE_PH_Active': ['EXP_PREPARE_DATA'],
        'exp_MOBILE_PH_NO': ['lkp_SH_MOBILE_PH_Active']},
    3: {'FIL_InsertNewRecord': ['UPD_ForceInserts'], 'FIL_UpdateChangedRecord': ['UPD_ChangedUpdate'],
        'EXP_DetectChanges': ['FIL_InsertNewRecord', 'FIL_UpdateChangedRecord'],
        'LKP_GetData': ['FIL_UpdateChangedRecord', 'EXP_DetectChanges']},
    4: {'UPD_ForceInserts': ['DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_Insert'], 'UPD_ChangedUpdate': ['DIM_NRC_CUSTOMER_TMP_Insert']}
}

# Create a new Excel workbook
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Desktop\\multiple_sheets_details_new.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.create_sheet(title="MAPPING", index=0)

# Write headers
headers = [f'Stage{i}' for i in nested_dict.keys()]
sheet.append(headers)

for col, inner_dict in enumerate(nested_dict.values(), 1):
    row = 2  # Start from row 2 
    sheet.cell(row=row-1, column=col).font = Font(bold=True)  # Bold the header cells
    sheet.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col)].width = 60  # Set a larger column width
    for key in inner_dict:
        for item in inner_dict[key]:
            sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value = f"{key} -> {str(item)}"
            row += 1

# Save the workbook
workbook.save("C:\\Desktop\\multiple_sheets_details_new.xlsx")
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank u so much for your help. I will test it though it seems fine :)